# CSS - Undefined Spacing in Div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```css
    html {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
      color: #bdc3c7;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      background-color: #3E4651;
    }

    .nav {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .navBtn {
      font-size: 22px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      width: 24.8%;
      color: #bdc3c7;
    }

    .navBtn:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .infoCenter {
      height: 40%;
      width: 30%;
      background-color: black;
    }

    .totalsContainer {
      margin-top: 0px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid white;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .listingsContainer {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid white;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .infoLabel {
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .infoValue {
      font-size: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }



    .selected {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
    }

    .contents {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 525px;
      background-color: #25373D;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="infoCenter">
        <div class="totalsContainer">
          <h1 class="infoLabel totalPendingLbl">Total Pending</h1>
          <h2 id="#totalPending" class="infoValue" 
    totalPending">$100.00</h2>
          <h1 class="infoLabel totalAvailableLbl">Total Available</h1>
          <h2 id="#totalAvailable" class="infoValue 
    totalAvailable">$500.00</h2>
        </div>
          <div class="listingsContainer">
          <h1 class="infoLabel totalListingsLbl">Total Listings</h1>
          <h2 id="#totalListings" class="infoValue totalListings">10</h2>
          <h1 class="infoLabel listingsSiteLbl">Listings By Site</h1>
          <h2 id="#listingsonGoat" class="infoValue listingsonGoat">6</h2>
          <h2 id="#listingsonStockx" class="infoValue listingsonStockx">4</h2>
        </div>
</div>
```

and as shown in the picture provided, the first container in the main container is moved down about 10 pixels whenever I have no rule in css making it do that. I have no idea what is making this problem occur, but it has happened in many of my projects and is very frustrating. This is for my application so it will not fit regular browsers, but the problem still occurs there as well. Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the default browser rules are doing it?  Try normalizing/reseting(normalize.css/reset.css) everything before applying your rules.

Comment: That's a pretty nonsensical HTML structure btw., using h1/h2 headlines for all of those pieces of text does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

`inline-block`s by default align along their baseline, which - if they contain text - is the last line of text in there. To avoid this, you can use other `vertical-align` settings, for example `top` or `bottom`. Below I used `top` (for `.totalsContainer` and `.listingsContainer`)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: #3E4651;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navBtn {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 24.8%;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

.navBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.infoCenter {
  height: 40%;
  width: 32%;
  background-color: black;
}

.totalsContainer {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 100%;
}

.listingsContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 100%;
}

.infoLabel {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.infoValue {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
}

.contents {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 525px;
  background-color: #25373D;
}
```

```html
<div class="infoCenter">
  <div class="totalsContainer">
    <h1 class="infoLabel totalPendingLbl">Total Pending</h1>
    <h2 id="#totalPending" class="infoValue" totalPending ">$100.00</h2>
          <h1 class="infoLabel totalAvailableLbl ">Total Available</h1>
          <h2 id="#totalAvailable " class="infoValue totalAvailable ">$500.00</h2>
        </div>
          <div class="listingsContainer ">
          <h1 class="infoLabel totalListingsLbl ">Total Listings</h1>
          <h2 id="#totalListings " class="infoValue totalListings ">10</h2>
          <h1 class="infoLabel listingsSiteLbl ">Listings By Site</h1>
          <h2 id="#listingsonGoat " class="infoValue listingsonGoat ">6</h2>
          <h2 id="#listingsonStockx " class="infoValue listingsonStockx ">4</h2>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might as well align the boxes setting

```
.infoCenter {
  display: flex; 
}
```

if you're fine with using flexbox.

It allows you to remove the `display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align:top;` of the inner containers altogether, as flexboxes default align value is "stretch" - all elements will get equal height.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to make them fit side by side. You can solve that by adding float left to your totalsContainer:

```
.totalsContainer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```